# Iterate through elements in a list with shared element names in R

Tags: r, lapply

I have a list that looks something like this (a must-reduced version of a list with 301 sub-elements):

```
 myList <- list()
 myList$Speaker1 <- list("ID" = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
             "S1C1.Sonorant" = c(0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, -1),
             "S1C1.Consonantal" = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
             "S1C1.Voice" = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, -1),
             "S1C1.Nasal" = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, -1))
 myList$Speaker2 <- list("ID" = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
             "S1C1.Sonorant" = c(0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, -1),
             "S1C1.Consonantal" = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
             "S1C1.Voice" = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, -1),
             "S1C1.Nasal" = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, -1))
 myList$Speaker3 <- list("ID" = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
             "S1C1.Sonorant" = c(0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, -1),
             "S1C1.Consonantal" = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
             "S1C1.Voice" = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, -1),
             "S1C1.Nasal" = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, -1))
```

For each speaker, I want to run some functions through all the sub-elements that include the string `S1C1.`. So far, I have the following, which calls each column containing `S1C1` individually:

```
 my_matrix <- lapply(myList, FUN = function(element) {

    ones <- rep(1, nrow(element))  # count repeated rows

    sonorant_vec.S1C1 <- element$S1C1.Sonorant
    sonorant_mat.S1C1 <- (sonorant_vec.S1C1 %*% t(ones) - ones %*% t(sonorant_vec.S1C1))^2

    consonantal_vec.S1C1 <- element$S1C1.Consonantal
    consonantal_mat.S1C1 <- (consonantal_vec.S1C1 %*% t(ones) - ones %*% t(consonantal_vec.S1C1))^2

    voice_vec.S1C1 <- element$S1C1.Voice
    voice_mat.S1C1 <- (voice_vec.S1C1 %*% t(ones) - ones %*% t(voice_vec.S1C1))^2

    nasal_vec.S1C1 <- element$S1C1.Nasal
    nasal_mat.S1C1 <- (nasal_vec.S1C1 %*% t(ones) - ones %*% t(nasal_vec.S1C1))^2

 mat.S1C1 <- sonorant_mat.S1C1 + 
     consonantal_mat.S1C1 + 
     voice_mat.S1C1 + 
     nasal_mat.S1C1

   rownames(mat.S1C1) <- element$S1C1.S1C1
   colnames(mat.S1C1) <- element$S1C1.S1C1

   all_mat <- sqrt(mat.S1C1[,])

   return(all_mat)
    })
```

Is there a way I can iterate through all the sub-elements that start with the string `S1C1.`? The current code works but is very long!

Comment: try `mutate(across(starts_with(...` in `dplyr`

Comment: Since your list is a list of tibbles, I assume you use `dplyr`? I would expect the function inside `lapply` to start with something like `select(element, where(is.numeric) & starts_with("S1C1")) %>% ...`

Comment: +1 with @GregorThomas.  However, still for better explanation, please include a minimal reproducible example with the question.